# How to set up various websphere server inside a cluster

Tags: cluster, service, websphere, ihs

I want to install 2 individual websphere server (AppServer option in the installer) and later install the deployment manager and federate those server under it to make then a cluster.

Any help is welcome.

I already figured how to use wasservice[1] to up nodeagent and my faulty server1 (which wasn't starting on machine startup), and installed IBM HTTP Server, yet it's not in cluster.

Thanks in advance.

[1]http://pastebin.com/peihzsHY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to facilitate this sort of knowledge you've gotta get a bunch of background.  First of all to federate an environment the recommended method for IBM WAS is to use the network deployment method.

Once you've done that you need to re-enable security, make sure you've got the nodeagents setup to start automatically (before your server agents) and reconfigure your HTTP plugins.

It's possible, but honestly if you've got the capacity to configure the DM now, I would do it so you don't have to go back and do it later.  You can always add more nodes to a cluster (even if it's just a cluster of one) and not have to worry about configuring it after it's up in production.

(Some resources for the uninitiated on [federating WAS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.commerce.admin.doc/tasks/tigfederate.htm) I also found it useful for self learning to use the [IBM Education assistant](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.wpi_v6/wpswid/6.0.1/Clustering.html) videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an existing standalone server to the DM with the addNode command.